# How to use gif symbols with ArcGis

Tags: arcgis, esri, arcgis-runtime, esri-maps, arcgis-runtime-net

I'm using the ArcGis .NET SDK from Esri and was hoping to use a .gif symbol similar to the following, although even though I see that a HTTP request was sent for the image the map doesn't display the gif. If I select an online .png it works fine.

```
var symbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol(new Uri("http://gifs.com/awesome.gif"));
```

I was hoping this would work since I read [Bring Your Points to Life with GIF Symbols](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/mapping/bring-your-points-to-life-with-gif-symbols/).

And ideas? Maybe gifs just aren't supported in the .NET runtime sdk, and if that's the case any good ways to get an animated symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GIF files are not supported by the runtime.

Animated symbols is something that's being thought about how to bring to the entire ArcGIS System (not just runtime), but there's no definite timeline for that at this point.

The best you could do would be to do your own frame-based animation (ie frequently update the symbol properties), but be careful with this, as it could risk causing texture memory issues on some devices, so don't overdo it...

Comment: Yeah it doesn't seem natively supported at this time. But I'm looking into using a CompositeSymbol and showing/hiding the internal symbols on a timer.